# What do I do if my F3 button doesnt work on minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

About a month ago, I noticed that my <kbd>F3</kbd> button stopped working. I need to be able to press it so I can figure out what level I'm on and thus hunt for diamonds.

I tried <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> too, and it didn't work either. What can I do?

Comment: As an alternative way to search for diamonds you can simply dig down to bedrock and then count up from there - diamonds are found on layers 1 - 16 so counting up from the bottom is easier than counting down from anywhere else.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like your <kbd>F3</kbd> key may be broken on your keyboard.  You can check by opening Internet Explorer or Chrome (browsers) and press <kbd>F3</kbd>, it should open the "search this page" box along the top.  Same as if you pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>F</kbd>.  I don't know any mac keyboard mappings.

[Here is a post that describes how to remap your keys for either Windows or Mac](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/543922-remap-f3-key/).

Comment: My F3 is broke but idk what post on the link helps

Comment: Looks like you are on windows.  Try this one: http://lifehacker.com/5883003/the-best-key-remapper-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

You can press escape and go to options. Then go to controls and change F3 to another key that is working.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to install a minimap mod that displays your coordinates including your Y that you wanted.