# My f3 key doesn't work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm running mine craft on a desktop and don't have a function key, yet my f3 key is a special key, so it doesn't work in mine craft properly.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Could you edit your post to include an explicit question?

Comment: I know you can remap other keybinds in the game but Ive never tried to remap the F keys, so not sure if its possible for those. For my laptop, it had special keys mapped to the F keys and I had to go into the BIOS and turn off that feature so that by default the F keys did F key stuff and not the special stuff they were made for. But like you said, your keyboard doesnt have a function key so this might not be an option.

Comment: *is a special key* - what do you mean? Like on a basic laptop only you don't have a function key (fn)?  If it is a special key, then what is the special key?

Comment: @PausePause i have a really old mechanical keyboard with special f-key bindings, but it lacks a fn key, so it cant be solved that way. When i press any of the f-keys i just crouch for a millisecond and am unable to reassign any of my f-keys ingame

Comment: @TimmyJim it is supposed to shortcut to file explorer

Comment: Might also be a duplicate of [this](/questions/152221/what-do-i-do-if-my-f3-button-doesnt-work-on-minecraft)

Comment: @MBraedley thanks but no, it just sends me straight to explorer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use F3 to get my coordinates when my laptop makes F3 a special key?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132160/how-do-i-use-f3-to-get-my-coordinates-when-my-laptop-makes-f3-a-special-key)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I do if my F3 button doesnt work on minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/152221/what-do-i-do-if-my-f3-button-doesnt-work-on-minecraft)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)'s key spy to figure out which key combination the "F3" key is actually issuing, and then running a AutoHotkey script to intercept that key and convert it to an actual F3 keypress.